# How to print columns from different files?

Tags: awk, carriage-return

I have problem that numbers from different files are not in one line.

I tried:

```
 paste file1 file2 file3|awk '{print $1, $2, $6, $10}'
```

file1:

```
a b c
```

file2:

```
d e f
```

file3:

```
g h i
```

output is:

```
a b
e
h
```

Desired output:

```
a b e h
```

it is columns 1 2 from file1, column 2 from file2 and column 2 from file3

Comment: What is the logic to print `a b e h`? just random? or first 2 columns from 1st file and 2nd column from the other two files

Comment: Yes I want to print columns $1 $2 from file1 and column $2 from file2 and file3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest first to fix end of line in your files:

```
dos2unix file1 file2 file3
```